# Escaping single quote for a specific pattern using vim

Tags: regex, vim

Consider the below line for example

`'{"place":"buddy's home"}'`

I want to replace the single quote in `buddy's` only. Single quotes at the start and end of line had to be intact. So the resulting line would look like.

`'{"place":"buddy\'s home"}'`

There could be multiple lines with multiple occurrences of such single quotes in each line. I have to escape all of them except at the start and end of line.

I'm able to find out such pattern using vim regex `:/.'.` This pattern ensures that single quote is surrounded by two characters and is not at start or at the end of line. But I'm having trouble how to replace the `y's` into `y\'s` at all places.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the regex `.'.` is accurate enough then you can substitute all occurrences with:

```
:%s/.\zs'\ze./\\'/g
```

Instead of using `\ze` and `\zs` you could use groups `(...)` as well. However I find this version slightly more readable.

See `:h /\zs` and `:h /\ze` for further information.

Answer (score 1):

```
:%s/\(.\)'\(.\)/\1\\'\2/gc
```

- `:%s/` substitute over the whole buffer (see `:help range` to explain the `%`)
- `\(.\)` match a character and save it in capture group 1 (see `:help \(`)
- `'` a literal `'`
- `\(.\)` match a character and save it in capture group 2
- `/` replace by
- `\1` capture group 1 (see `:help \1`)
- `\\'` this is a `\'` (you need to escape the backslash)
- `\2` capture group 2
- `/gc` replace globally (the whole line) and ask for confirmation (see `:help :s_flags`)

You can omit the `c` option if you are sure all replaces are legit.

---

As [kongo2002](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52995455/8699120) says in his answer you could replace the capture groups by `\zs` and `\ze`:

- `\zs` will start a match and discard everything before
- `\ze` will end a match and discard everything after

See `:help \ze` and `:help \zs`.